# .net MVC scaffolding t4-template append DbContext

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently trying to create my own visual studio scaffolder. It works great but there is one thing I can't seem to figure out.

In the default MVC5 scaffolder when you create a new controller for a new model, the scaffolder automatically appends the DbContext with the new model. So each time I run the default scaffolder it updates the DbContext class.

I can't seem to find how this is done. All I can find online are examples where they use the scaffolding to create new files, not to append existing ones.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!